# C++ STL alternative to nested loops in a vector

Tags: c++, loops, nested, stl, c++20

As Sean Parent once required I'd like to eliminate raw loops in some code using C++20. Does it makes sense? If so, how?

In my example it's a vector of objects I need to merge under some conditions.
So there seem to be two sub tasks for me.

The first is how could I replace nested loops by using STL algorithms.
This is the kind a nested loops I write about:

```cpp
for (size_t i = vector1.size() - 1; i > 0; --i)
{
    for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j)
    {
           if (isMergable(vector1[i], vector1[j]))
           {
                    merge(vector1[i], vector1[j])
           }
    }
}
```

The second is how to do it when the content of the vector changes while looping. As mentioned I'd like to merge two objects under particular conditions, which means the destination object absorbs some properties of the source object and the source object vanishes.

I guess when consider this sub tasks separately the result after the second sub task will not be the same as when look at this as one task. I haven't found a fitting STL algorithm, even to replace that  nested loops.

I'm glad to recieve any help I can learn from.

Thanks.

EDIT
An object could be like that:

```cpp
struct myObject {
    int number;
    std::string word;
};
```

This object may have a number value or a word value. A merge of two objects is possible when both have filled the number or both have filled the word. A merge would mean to sum up the numbers or to concatenate the words. The vector would consists of an amount of objects, some with a number, some with a word. After merging the vector consists only of two objects: one with sumed up numbers, the other with concatenated words.

Comment: This depends a lot on the underlying problem you're trying to solve, its requirements and what is meant by "merging" elements. As for possible ways to solve it without explicit loops, it could possible by using [standard ranges](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges), or [the range library](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3) the standard is based on.

Comment: First thing first, make sure your algorithm is necessarily O(n²). The situation you describe looks quite odd.

Comment: in c++23 [cartesian product](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/ranges/cartesian_product_view) will come to the ranges library

Comment: what is `merge` ? If you merely want to replace a loop you can always use `std::for_each`, but to get something more expressive you need to consider what the loop actually does

Comment: If you want to end up with a vector of unique elements you could use : `std::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end());  std::unique(vector.begin(); vector.end());`, or replace your `std::vector` with a `std::set`. But all these are ideas, what we really need to know is WHAT you are trying to achieve

Comment: Oh, thank you for that rapid replies.
To detail my request. An object could be like that:
class myObject
{
 int number;
 std::string word;
}

This object may have a number value or a word value.
A merge of two object is possible when both have filled the number or both have filled the word.
A merge would mean to sum up the numbers or to concatenate the words.
The vector would consists of an amount of objects, some with a number, some with a word.
After merging the vector consists only of two objects: one with sumed up numbers, the other with concatenated words.

Comment: *"After merging the vector consists only of two objects: one with sumed up numbers, the other with concatenated words"*. How about 2 `std::accumulate` then?

Comment: Nested lambdas is the answer you're looking for, but regular for-loops are a perfectly fine way to do what you're doing, no reason to shoehorn everything into STL algorithms

Comment: the thruth is not in the extremes but somewhere in between. When Sean Parent suggests to eliminate all loops, thats because most code is leaning towards raw loops and can use more algorithms. If code programmers write had no loops at all but only algorithms, perhaps someone would come up with a  talks titled "Free your algorithms, write more loops" ;). I am not objecting the greater picture, more algorithms is good, but banning raw loops completely would lead to weird code too.

Comment: please [edit] the question to clarify what the code does rather than only explaining it in comments.

Comment: Smells like a relational database issue, so let's apply some DB techniques.  Throw all your data into a single `std::vector` (a.k.a. table).  Create a `std::map<key-field, vector-index>`  This is known as an index table.  Look up an item by its key using the `std::map`.  Extract the version index and use the version index to fetch the item from the `std::vector`.  You can create multiple index tables for different sorting methods.  The index tables allow you to search the vector without sorting the vector each time you change the search key.